# how to validate select box in laravel (without using JS)

Tags: laravel

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Publication Status</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select name="publicationStatus" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
            <option value="1">Published</option>
            <option value="0">Unpublished</option>
          </select>
        <span class="text-danger">{{$errors->has('publicationStatus')? $errors->first('publicationStatus'):''}}</span>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

my controller

```
public function storeManufacturer(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request,[
        'manufacturerName'=>'required',
        'manufacturerDescription'=>'required',
        'publicationStatus'=>'required', 
      ]);
```

above 'manufacturerName' & 'manufacturerDescription' is working but **publicationStatus** is not validate in the same way.Maybe the reason is that contain multiple value.

Comment: I have updated your code. Check if it works or not? I think the default empty value for the first option will works.

Comment: what are you getting in `$request->publicationStatus` ?? have you `dd($request->publicationStatus)`. i think you should assign `<option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>` to get empty value then it will be validate.

Comment: dd is oky but after that it gives SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Select Manufacturer' for column 'publicationStatus' at row 1 (22007)
 error when i dont select any option from Select Manufacturer

Comment: exactly i got SQLSTATE error message....

Answer (score 0):

You could check data of $request with dd() in your controller firstly:

```
dd($request->publicationStatus);
```

Comment: it's working and i got "Select Manufacturer" this message